# Make pdo::query static

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I get this error when I run the code below. I have normally used the msql functions butI have tried to get to use the PDO instead. What is wrong ?

Fatal error: Non-static method PDO::query() cannot be called statically on line 14

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['username']) AND isset($_POST['password'])) {

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password_hash = md5($password);

if (!empty($username) AND !empty($password) ) {


$query = "SELECT 'id' FROM `userdatabase` WHERE 'email'='$username' AND      'password'='$password_hash'";

if($query_run = PDO::query($query)){

$query_num_rows = PDO::rowcount($query_run);
if ($query_num_rows==0){
echo 'invalid password/username';

} else {
echo 'Username/password  = correct';
}


}


} else {
echo 'You must enter a password..';
}

} 


?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::` sign is used to call methods that are defined as static, which means you don't need to create instance of an object to call this method. `query()` method is not static which means that you need to create `PDO` object first and then call `query()` method on that object.

This should look like this:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';
$pdo = new  PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$result = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM table');  //here $result is a set of results that can be accessed like arrays;
```

Comment: 1 thing to keep in mind: result holds, what is called a PDOStatement, not the actual result of the query, to acces those: `$actualResults = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`, or 1 by 1 `while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){echo $row['afield'];}`

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you can use static method, how you suppose to connect to your database?

PDO need to be a instance because the constructor (`__construct()`) will connect to database. If you have static methods, you can't do `PDO::__construct($params)`, because PHP have not static constructor.

So, instantiate PDO:

```
$pdo = new  PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=localhost', 'root', 'password');
```

And do the query:

```
$result = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1');
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message says it all. You're calling the `query` method as a static method (a method that doesn't require the class to be instantiated), while it's not a static.

Just to give a bit more background as to why you can't make it a static function (since your question leads me to believe that's how you want to solve this error).

- When instantiating the PDO object, you pass the database host, username, password, type of db and default databse to its constructor. (these are not all required parameters). A connection to the database server is established, so you can query for data.
- If your query method were static, you'd either have to connect, query, disconnect and return the results, for each query you want to run. Obviously this is *not* a good approach.
- The PDO object allows you to do much, much more than just executing queries: suppose your DB  is running on the InnoDB engine. A static query method would just attempt to execute a `DELETE` query, but leaves no room for a safety net when things go wrong. PDO provides the `$db->commit();` and `$db->rollBack();` methods, to prevent data corruption.

There are many, many more good reasons why you shouldn't even think about extending the PDO class, and making static member functions, but you can find out for yourself reading [the docs](http://www.php.net/pdo).

In your example, you want to get the rowcount after the query is executed. Think about what that means: there is no instance to assign this value to one of its properties, nor is there a connection to the database on which you just ran your query. The only way to get a rowcount in your case would be to rerun the query and count. IMO, that's just silly

Answer (score 0):

Your query must be executed on a database connexion.

Your can't use `query` as a static function, but use `$con->query()` instead of.

Without any PDO object specified, how can PDO know which connexion use ? (you can have more than one)