# PDO update query isn't overwriting data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this simple chunk of code that updates the user's last login with the current timestamp. If `last_login` is set to NULL and then I perform an `UPDATE` query it will work, however it won't if `last_login` already has a value.

Here's my code:

PHP:

```
$time = time();
$user_id = $active_user->id;
DB::query('UPDATE `users` SET `last_login` = ? WHERE `id` = ?;', array($time, $user_id));
```

Comment: Do you have any error ?

Comment: No errors are showing, it's just not updating

Comment: I think `query` is only for select. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323065/update-query-with-pdo-and-mysql) how do you use PDO with update.

Comment: I have a custom DB query object, I use this all the time and it works fine.

Comment: Show the code of your custom DB query.

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose without the code in your static `query` method. All I can say for now is to ensure you're developing with `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On` in your `php.ini` file as well as setting PDO attributes `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`

Comment: Also, got any triggers in your database?

Comment: try updating with a hard coded timestamp first to ensure if the update code really fires.

Comment: Your query is not going to work with your current configuration, see this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172777/make-pdoquery-static